# IAAS VM Azure Diagnostic application logs blob storage not always updating

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

On IAAS virtual machines I have Azure Diagnostics setup for IIS logs, and Application logs stored on a separate disk to be copied to blob storage.

The IIS logs are being updated fine, and kept up to date on a regular period.

For the application logs, they are written to disk, using log4net.
And then copied to blob storage via Azure Diagnostics.
There is a log file per day by default, and multiple log files.

It appears that when new files are created, they are copied over to blob storage fine. E.g. just after midnight all the new files are copied up to blob storage.

The issue appears to be when existing files are updated, they are not always being updated in blob storage.
It's seems a bit hit and missing as to if any files are updated over a few hours, or if one of the files is copied over, or on occasion all the files are updated in blob storage.

I've tried restarting the virtual machine, after which on some of the machines some/all of the logs files were then updated in blob storage.
But then on others not.

And then later on all the VMs I had restarted they all appeared to update their log files around the same time.
And the VMs which I hadn't which still didn't have updated blogs, I then restarted and they too had updated blob with the application logs.

Before going back to being intermittent updates to blob storage.

Anyone seen anything like this?

Suggestions on how to make the transfer of application logs to blob storage via Azure Diagnostics more reliable?

Comment: how are you copying the files? what kind of blob types?

Comment: Azure Diagnostic Extensions for IAAS Virtual Machines.

Comment: Storage Account General - blob service - container